# initialize list with n independent instances

Tags: python, list, initialization

So, I searched for how to initialize a list in python with a number of cells.

I found this syntax

`l = [T] * n`

ok, but I got massively gotcha-ed by this and looked for the cause of the bug this was creating for over an hour. The instances of `T` are somehow linked, as if the cells had a reference to a single instance of `T`!

But this is only true for *some* types. See:

```
l1 = [int] * 10

print l1[0]
print l1[1]

l1[0] = 12

print l1[0]
print l1[1]


l2 = [Counter()] * 10

for key, value in l2[0].items():
    print key, value

for key, value in l2[1].items():
    print key, value

l2[0]["a"] +=1

for key, value in l2[0].items():
    print key, value

for key, value in l2[1].items():
    print key, value
```

output:

```
<type 'int'>
<type 'int'>
12
<type 'int'>
a 1
a 1
```

As a side question: Why is this so inconsistent and why does the duplicate design exist the first place?

So, how can I do the initialization with a number of `T`s without this weird duplicate behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension:

```
l = [f() for _ in range(n)]
```

It's a common gotcha with mutable types:

```
>>> l = [[]] * 2
>>> l[0].append(4)
>>> l
[[4], [4]]

>>> l = [5] * 2
>>> l[0] += 1
>>> l
[6, 5]
```

Comment: thanks, what is the design idea behind this behavior though?

Comment: @lotolmencre mutable types don't need to copied when passed around, just a reference to them is enough, and they can be modified too. (It's a little more complicated than that, but you can read more about that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)).

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you put the abstraction of the type **int** into each list element.  Then you changed *one* of those locations.

In the second case, you put a reference to a Counter into each list element.  Then you changed the Counter, not an individual list element.  You didn't touch any of the references, merely the object to which they point.

In the second case, try doing the *same* thing you did in the first:

```
l2 = [Counter()] * 10

for key, value in l2[0].items():
    print key, value

for key, value in l2[1].items():
    print key, value

l2[0] = 12
```

Does this un-confuse you?